# NSURLCACHE policy to update cache data if website is reachable and so always load cache

Tags: ios, swift, caching, nsurlcache, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

I'm totally new to swift and iOS development.
I'm trying to do a webview app and i need to update the cache because the website can change but i also need to be able to access it while offline.
Is there any premade cache policy i can use in order to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple dev support member, `NSURLCache was designed as a general purpose cache and doesn’t have the infrastructure needed to reliably support an offline mode`. Which means if you want to create an offline mode, you must implement caching yourself.

Source: [NSURLRequest.CachePolicy thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/79999)